# Is it possible that an awarded bounty takes time to be effective?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties, expired-bounty

On [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/590628/why-cant-download-the-torrent-file/591343#590628) the OP told me that he awarded me the bounty with the bounty icon bellow the accepted icon, but the bounty is not effectively awarded. Is this possible?

I know that the automatic system will award me the bounty after the grace period as the answer is accepted.

Comment: From here, he bounty is showing as not awarded, but still within the grace period before it's automatically half-awarded (15 hours to go at time of comment).

Comment: @intika _"the OP told me that he awarded me the bounty"_ I can't see any evidence for that in the comments.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i did helped him on IRC... and deleted the comments linking to my IRC nickname...

Comment: From past experience, many people (usually new to SO/SE) think that accepting an answer while they have active bounty means instant award of the bounty. Most likely that's the case here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, it always happens instantaneously. As you can see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/592614/timeline), another bounty was awarded to one of your answers today at 03:10:00 UTC:

[image]

and it immediately showed in your [reputation history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/120919/intika?tab=reputation):

[image]

In the case you described, the OP was simply misinformed, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, yes i guess that the OP just did not click or something similar.